# How to prove $L^{p}$ is separable?

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin asserts that $L^{p}(\mathbb{S}^{1})$ is separable for $1\le p<\infty$, but not for $p=\infty$. I am wondering why this is true.

For any $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{S}^{1})$ we should be able to approximate it via the standard trigonometric series, hence lead to separability if we let the coefficents be rational. But I am wondering why for $L^{\infty}$ we cannot use the following system $$f_{n}=\sum^{2^{k}}_{n=1}a_{n}\chi(E_{n})$$ where $E_{n}$ is the characteristic function on intervals of length $[\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}]$ and $a_{n}\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then every function in $L^{\infty}$ should be able to be approximated by some $f_{n}$ with $n,k$ large enough. The whole set of $f_{n,k}$ would have same cardinality as the algebraic numbers, hence should be countable.

Comment: How do you approximate the characteristic function of an interval of length $\pi/3$ by such functions?

Comment: I can approximate it by selecting the small intervals being included in the large interval. But I see where the problem is.

Comment: Right, that doesn't successfully approximate it in $L^\infty$ norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $L^\infty(S^1)$ you can found an uncountable $1-$separated set of functions, so $L^\infty$ isn't separable. An example
$$
\left\lbrace \chi_I\quad \big\vert \quad \forall I\subset S^1\right\rbrace 
$$
indeed
$$
\forall I, I'\quad I\neq I'\quad \rightarrow \quad \Vert \chi_I - \chi_{I'}\Vert_{\infty}=1.
$$

Comment: I see. So simple functions would not work for $L^{\infty}$ norms. I will think about how to prove it.